# Loop through an XML object's field values PHP

Tags: php, xml, string, simplexml

I have an XML that looks like this...

```
<fields>
  <field>
    <id>86</id>
    <source>system</source>
    <type>integer</type>
    <name>bounce_count</name>
    <label>Bounce count</label>
    <validation/>
    <store-locally>true</store-locally>
    <display-in-profile>false</display-in-profile>
    <include-in-export>false</include-in-export>
    <lma_display>false</lma_display>
    <newsletters></newsletters>
  </field>
</fields>
```

I need to loop in through the value of every tag inside `<field>`. I tried the following (result is the XML), first I got everything within the field tag...

```
$value = $result->field
$value = simplexml_load_string($value);
```

If I `var_dump()` this it looks as so...

> object(SimpleXMLElement)#47 (11) { ["id"]=> string(3) "153" ["source"]=> string(6) "client" ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["name"]=> string(4) "name" ["label"]=> string(4) "Name" ["validation"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#48 (0) { } ["store-locally"]=> string(4) "true" ["display-in-profile"]=> string(4) "true" ["include-in-export"]=> string(4) "true" ["lma_display"]=> string(4) "true" ["newsletters"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#46 (0) { } }

Next I try looping through the fields inside `field`

```
foreach ($value as $single_field) {
    echo $single_field;
}
```

But I get no output. If I `var_dump()` `$single_field` I get the same result as above. I need to loop through the values within each field. So for the XML above I need to store the following values...

```
86
system
integer
bounce_count
Bounce Count
true
false
false
false
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to iterate over children of the element, you need to use [SimpleXMLElement::children](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) in your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($value->children() as $single_field) {
    echo $single_field . "\n";
}
```